# Prove that matrix can be square of matrix with real entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Prove that matrix

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}

can be square of matrix with all real entries.

I have found one such matrix to be

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&-1\\0&2&-1\end{bmatrix} but is there an elegant way to do it without any trial and error?

Comment: This is a question of JEE Advanced 2017, which was conducted all India today!

Comment: @JaideepKhare Is that a problem? As far as I can tell it's over, so there's no problem in answering the question.

Comment: No problem @ArnaudD. . I was just mentioning it since my brother also appeared for it and I had just discussed that problem. There is no problem at all. The exam was over at 5:00PM   (Indian standard Time ; GMT + 5:30)

Comment: I just found an answer  compiling some reference on this site about square roots of matrices : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/348868/245577

Comment: @Mathematics Hey, Mathematics I'm curious what do you think about my solution of your problem. Is it satisfying your expectations or it is still something missing ? ... – Widawensen 3 hours ago

Answer (score 14):

Sure. Your matrix is the matrix of a half-turn around the $x$-axis. Just take a quarter of a turn around the same axis:$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\text{ or }\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 7):

Hint. Think about the geometry of the linear transformation $T$ of space that matrix represents. Then look for a transformation $S$ such that $S^2 = T$.

Comment: In particular: the matrix given is a $180^\circ$ rotation in the $yz$-plane.

Comment: Anything that works on a less trivial example?

Answer (score 3):

I will try to present  *a solution "without any trial and error"*.

Here we have a matrix $F$ in the form 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0_{1 \times 2} \\ 0_{2 \times 1} & A_{2 \times 2} \end{bmatrix}$ so if $G^2=F$ then $G$ can be in the form $\begin{bmatrix}
\pm 1 &  0_{1 \times 2} \\ 0_{2 \times 1} & B_{2 \times 2} \end{bmatrix}$ where $B^2=A$.

Now let's concentrate on $B^2=\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 &  0 \\ 0  & -1 \end{bmatrix} $.

We have two matrix equations 
$B^2=-I$  i.e.
$B^2+I=0$

and general equation from Cayley-Hamilton theorem  for $ 2 \times 2$ matrices
$B^2-\text{tr}(B)B+\det(B)I=0$.

Comparing both equations we obtain

$\text{tr(B)}=0$   , $ \det(B)=1$.

So if we denote $ B=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\c  & d\end{bmatrix} $  then $d=-a$ and consequently $-a^2-bc=1$.
These conditions are sufficient  to obtain a solution not only with **real** numbers, but even with **integer** values.

For example
if $a=0$ then $b=1$, $c=-1$

($b,c$  should have always opposite signs because -$a^2-bc$ has to be positive - possible other solution $-1,1$, also $a$ and $d$ can be switched)

if $a=1$ then $b=2$, $c=-1$
if $a=2$ then $b=5$, $c=-1$
if $a=3$ then $b=5$, $c=-2$
...
if $a=8$ then $b=5$, $d=-13$   , etc... infinite number of solutions - for every integer $a$ we can find proper integer values of $b$ and $c$ from $-bc=a^2+1$..

Let's check the last listed solution.
Indeed

$  \begin{bmatrix} 8 & 5 \\-13  & -8\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 8 & 5 \\-13  & -8\end{bmatrix}    =   \begin{bmatrix} 8 \cdot {8} - 5\cdot 13  & 8\cdot 5 - 5 \cdot 8  \\ -13\cdot 8 + 8 \cdot 13 & -13\cdot 5 +8\cdot 8\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\0  & -1\end{bmatrix} $ .

Answer (score 2):

Here is a practical computational way of solving this, which has the advantage of generalizing to more difficult problems for which the "tricks' used in the other answers may not apply.  This does not constitute a mathematical "proof", but it is a constructive and practical applied math solution.  Solution using YALMIP under MATLAB.

```
x=sdpvar(3,3,'full')
optimize(x^2==[1 0 0;0 -1 0;0 0 -1],[],sdpsettings('solver','baron'))

disp(value(x))
    1.0000         0         0
         0   -0.3562   -0.9815
         0    1.1481    0.3562

disp(value(x^2))
    1.0000         0         0
         0   -1.0000         0
         0         0   -1.0000
```

Now to show the power of this approach, let's say we want to find a square root, such that the (3,3) element is minimized, subject to the constraint that all elements of the square root have magnitude less than or equal to 5.

```
x=sdpvar(3,3,'full')
optimize([x^2==[1 0 0;0 -1 0;0 0 -1],-5<=x(:)<=5],x(3,3),sdpsettings('solver','baron'))

disp(value(x))
   -1.0000         0         0
         0    4.8990   -5.0000
         0    5.0000   -4.8990

disp(value(x^2))
    1.0000         0         0
         0   -1.0000         0
         0         0   -1.0000
```

Comment: @MarkLStone What 'a trick' have you noticed in my solution? It's just a complete method. Could you obtain from your Matlab functions for example than all entries in lower right $ 2 \times 2$ matrix be prime numbers ?

Comment: @ Widawensen Sorry, the "tricks" referred to the other solutions. My approach doesn't do everything for everyone, but can do things other approaches can't.  New approaches are possible than were a century ago.

Comment: @MarkLStone Yes Mark, your approach is interesting and provides something really new, but if it is true that the question is from an exam I think  it wouldn't be allowed to use  Matlab on the exam, but anyway thank you for new information, it really deserves upvoting..

Answer (score 2):

Think of the construction of $\mathbf C$ via $2\times2$-matrices: if $J=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, then
$$J^2=-I=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus, using block multiplication, one obvious solution is
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$