# Predicting if a $3 \times 3$ matrix has a real square root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Here are a few $3 \times 3$ matrices

A)$$
\begin{pmatrix}   1&    0&    0\\
    0  & 1 &   0\\
    0&    0  &  1\end{pmatrix}$$B)$$
\begin{pmatrix}   1&    0&    0\\
    0  & 1 &   0\\
    0&    0  &  -1\end{pmatrix}$$C)$$
\begin{pmatrix}   1&    0&    0\\
    0  & -1 &   0\\
    0&    0  &  -1\end{pmatrix}$$D)$$
\begin{pmatrix}   -1&    0&    0\\
    0  & -1 &   0\\
    0&    0  &  -1\end{pmatrix}$$

How can say if these matrices are the square of a $3 \times 3$ matrix with real entries or not?

Comment: C=D. Think about eigenvalues.

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290545/prove-that-matrix-can-be-square-of-matrix-with-real-entries?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A necessary condition for a real matrix to have a real square root is to have a **non-negative** determinant.

Indeed, if $A=B^2$, then $\det(A)=\det(B)^2\geqslant 0$.

**Method.** If $A$ is diagonalizable and has positive eigenvalue, a square root can be found taking the square root of its eigenvalues, namely if $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$, then $B=P\Lambda^{1/2}P^{-1}$ is a square root of $A$.

Comment: This only helps in $B)$.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there any way by which I can find the square root also??

Comment: @OpenBall Sure, I just dropped a useful observation for more general matrices. When the matrices are diagonalizable or even diagonal things are a lot easier.

Comment: (Non-negative determinant)

Comment: @OpenBall True, but $A)$ is trivial and $C)=D)$ are covered in the question I linked to in the comments.

Comment: @ZacharySelk As a non-native English speaker, I always forget which term is used to say $\geqslant 0$. Thank you for the reminder!

Comment: No worries, +1 for the good answer!

Comment: (Foreign English speaker) @ZacharySelk