# Question involving nilpotent or self-inverse matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, for $n\geq 2$. Which of the following statements are true?

1. $A^{2n}=0 \implies A^n=0$
2. $A^2=I \implies A=\pm I$
3. $A^{2n}=I \implies A^{n}=\pm I$

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: For $2$ take $A$ to be the reflection in the $x$-axis ($n=2$).

Comment: Being on this website for 5 years, you should be aware of the rules defined in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking) about asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

1. Let $A=U^{-1}(D+N)U$ be the Jordan form for $A$ over the complex numbers, where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ is zero everywhere excep for ones right above the main diagonal. Then $A^{2n}=U^{-1}(D+N)^{n}U=U^{-1}(D^{2n}+...)U$, where all matrices in $...$ are strictly upper triangular. Therefore $D=0$. But then $A^n=U^{-1}N^nU=0$ since $N^{n}=0$.
2. Take a diagonal matrix of size $2$ with a $1$ and a $-1$ in the diagonal.
3. Take the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0&...&0&1\\1&0&0&...&0&0\\0&1&0&...&0&0\\.&.&.&...&.&.\\0&0&0&...&1&0\end{matrix}\right)$ of size $2n$ for $n>1$. For $n=1$ use the previous example. The reason why this matrix works is because its characteristic polynomial is $x^{2n}-1$. Therefore its eigenvalues are the $2n$ roots of unity and in particular different. Therefore, over the complex numbers you can diagonalize it. The equations $A^{2n}=I$ and $A^n=\pm I$ remain the same by passing to the diagonalization. Now, while the diagonal becomes all ones when raised to the power $2n$, not all of them turn real when raised to the power $n$. That is why $A^n$ is not even going to be diagonal.

   If you want to avoid the complex numbers argument you can just notice that this matrix gives a permutation of the vector when applied to the standard basis. It rotates them $e_1\to e_2\to e_3\to...\to e_n\to e_1$. And this applying this permutation over and over doesn't return to the identity until you do the full $2n$ applications.

Answer (score 1):

For 2) Try$$A=\begin{pmatrix}3&8\\-1&-3\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $2$ see [this my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290545/prove-that-matrix-can-be-square-of-matrix-with-real-entries/2328248#2328248), the procedure is similar (description is too long to repeat it  again - I hope it is unnecessary)  -  there are infinitely many matrices $ 2 \times 2$ which give $A^2=I$

The first statement seems to be true as multiplication by $A$ must be at least $-1$ rank lowering operation so if it succeeded to lower it by $2n-1 $ to zero then also it will succeed to lower rank by $n-1$ multiplications (nilpotent matrix has additionally all eigenvalues equal to $0$ so its rank is the most $n-1$ ). If the $n \times n$ matrix is nilpotent then always $A^n  =0$.

For 3)  rotation in 3d space   about $z$ axis by $60^\circ$ is a good example where $R^6=I$ but $R^3 \neq \pm I$

Comment: @Peyton have you Peyton not notced That n denotes also a dimension of the matrix.? Your example has dimension 2 SO n=2 not 1.

Comment: @peyton SO have you Peyton only used my comment to improve Your previous answer.? At least you could upvote my good answer...